# What does 歪な mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, nuances

In the anime called Quintessential Quintuplets, one of the girls is talking to their mother’s (who has already passed away) used to be homeroom teacher.

> The teacher: 僕は彼女の担任教師だったんだ 
> 君は若い頃のお母さんそっくりだ 
> The girl: そっくり… 
> The teacher: ああ　歪なほどね

The english sub says “You look exactly like your mother when she was young... To some warped extent”

This translation somehow doesn’t feel right to me, would you really say そっくり if it isn’t truly そっくり because it’s 歪?

The definition of 歪な　is:

> 形がゆがんで正常でない・こと（さま）。

To me, it feels as if the teacher is trying to convey that she is so そっくり to her mother, that it’s 正常でない (歪).

“You are the spitting image of her to an unbelievable extent” is how I would translate it.

Are the subs right, or is my intuition correct on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

いびつな means *distorted, deformed*, basically deviating from what it should be (Another reading [ひずみ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%AD%AA/#je-63274) may help understand the meaning better).

The sentence says the girl resembles her mother of young days **too** much. So another translation would be

- The girl: Looks like my mother...
- The teacher: Yes. Abnormally.